# How to start polling immediately?

Tags: javascript, polling

I am trying to use polling for a small check that is performed at an interval of 15 secs.

```
setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({ url: "aaa.com",
                success: function(data){
                showUpdate(data);
              }, dataType: "text"});
            }, 15000);
```

But this means that there is an initial delay of 15 secs, before the polling starts, which is not desired in my case.
How can i force the polling to start immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't look for smart solutions when simple ones do the job :

```
function check() {
   $.ajax({ url: "aaa.com",
     success: function(data){
     showUpdate(data);
   }, dataType: "text"});
}
check();
setInterval(check, 15000);
```

Alternatively, I'd generally prefer

```
function check() {
   $.ajax({ url: "aaa.com",
     success: function(data){
        showUpdate(data);
        setTimeout(check, 15000);
   }, dataType: "text"});  
}
check();
```

Because there wouldn't be a stack of calls in case of delayed response.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into a slightly more complex idea of having a callback function which handles the delay between calls, the easiest method is to just move the function out to a named function and just call it manually the first time round

```
function doSomething() {

$.ajax({ url: "aaa.com",
                success: function(data){
                showUpdate(data);
              }, dataType: "text"});

}

doSomething();

setInterval(doSomething, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
function immediatePoll(f, interval) {
    f();
    setInterval(f, interval);
}

immediatePoll(function(){
        $.ajax({ url: "aaa.com",
            success: function(data){
            showUpdate(data);
          }, dataType: "text"});
        }, 15000);
```