# Is it possible to set a 0 initial interval in react polling?

Tags: reactjs, polling

React polling is generally as below

```
useEffect(() => {
  const boo = async () => {
    do something
  }
  let timer = setInterval(boo, 3000);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, []);
```

So above code will do something every 3 seconds.

My question is can I have boo() run immediately then start polling?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start polling immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066266/how-to-start-polling-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to trigger immediately after the component renders.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const boo = () => {
    do something
  }
  boo(); //will make sure it is called immediately without the timer
  let timer = setInterval(boo, 3000);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, []) // [] will make sure it only happens on the first time
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah, I forgot to put the rest of the function, it's actually a async function in there.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const timer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const myFunc = async () => {
      const boo = async () => {
        console.log('boo');
        // do something
      };
      await boo();
      timer.current = setInterval(boo, 3000);
    };

    myFunc();
    return () => {
      if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer.current);
      }
    };
  }, [timer]);

  return <div />;
}
```

Comment: @user3685525 I've just updated my answer to support `async` function

Answer (score 0):

I like to just return the function if I want it to run immediately, I feel like it is the least verbose method:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const boo = () => {
    do something
    return boo;
  }
  let timer = setInterval(boo(), 3000);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}
```